# JavaFx save data into txt file - check file existence

Tags: java, text

I'm making a system to save data into txt.

1 - I've declared the file:

```
public static final File file = new File("src/window/data.txt");
```

2 - The system that is not working

```
public void checkData() throws Exception
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    if (scan.hasNext() == false)
    {
        System.out.println("file is empty");
        BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        fileWriter.write("test");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("file is not empty");

    }
}
```

it always return false which means print "file is empty".

Answer (score 1):

I have edited that code with `try-catch` statement and tried to `"data.txt"` that contains any data and it works:

```
public static final File file = new File("data.txt");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        if (!scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("file is empty");
            BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            fileWriter.write("test");  
        } else {
            System.out.println("file is not empty");
        }   
    } catch  (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

The output is `"file is not empty"`. Please try out my code and check if the path to your file is really correct.

Comment: WOW DUDE, tanks for that :D to the code gets 100% just maintain public static final File file = new File("src/window/data.txt"); and its worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You could use more recent features of Java, e. g. [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) and [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) in order to write a textfile and check for file existence and emptiness.

```
public static void writeFile(String filePath, List<String> lines) {

    try {

        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        boolean exists = Files.exists(path);

        System.out.println( "File " + path.getFileName() + " exists: " + exists);

        if( exists) {
            boolean empty = Files.size(path) == 0;
            System.out.println("Empty: " + empty);
        }

        Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        System.out.println("File written: " + path.getFileName());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Usage

```
writeFile("c:/temp/test.txt", Arrays.asList("Some Text"));
```

Comment: Dude thanks for the help :D but the Nichar's code worked perfectly.